# Is there an Ember.js equivalent to Backbone.js Router for history and hash changes?

Tags: javascript, html, backbone.js, history, ember.js

In Backbone.js you can use the Router to bind to # changes to navigate around a single-page HTML5 app.

Is there an equivalent for Ember.js? Or have I missed something fundamental about its design?

Comment: Wow... How do I give basically the same answer earlier but don't get the accepted answer? Interesting how StackOverflow works.

Comment: Oh I didn't filter by time - there was just slightly more information in ebryn's answer. Thanks though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are plans to write a router for Ember. It will likely be integrated with the Ember StateManager. For now, you can use [sproutcore-routing](https://github.com/emberjs-addons/sproutcore-routing) or another routing solution. I'm currently using sproutcore-routing successfully, but it has some limitations.

Comment: What improvements over sproutcore-routing are important to you for an ember router?

Comment: The main reason is sproutcore-routing isn't very well tested. There could also be some cleaner integration/conventions around the Ember StateManager.

Comment: Also, I don't think sproutcore-routing supports back button navigation in IE7 and IE6.

Comment: Ember's built in Router should be used instead.

Answer (score 3):

You may also want to have a look at [Ember RouteManager](https://github.com/ghempton/ember-routemanager)

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at that [Anatomy of a Complex Ember.js App Part I: States and Routes](http://codebrief.com/2012/02/anatomy-of-a-complex-ember-js-app-part-i-states-and-routes/) and 
[ember-routemanager](https://github.com/ghempton/ember-layout-example/tree/master/js/libs).

Comment: Yep. A lot has changed since I asked the question!

Answer (score 2):

I'd imagine this has been left out to keep things "loosely coupled". You could use a self-contained alternative, for instance Sammy or http://davisjs.com/.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check this out: https://github.com/emberjs-addons/sproutcore-routing

Answer (score 2):

Sproutcore-Statechart (for Ember) also has routing support now: https://github.com/emberjs-addons/sproutcore-statechart

Answer (score 0):

As of Ember 1.0, Ember has a built-in first-class Router.