# Correct way of building Ember.js addons?

Tags: ember.js

Ember.js has a number of [addons](https://github.com/emberjs-addons), but most lack any sort of installation instructions. I successfully built [sproutcore-routing](https://github.com/emberjs-addons/sproutcore-routing) ([e.g.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8886837/is-there-an-ember-js-equivalent-to-backbone-js-router-for-history-and-hash-chang)) by checking it out into ember.js/packages and hacking Rakefile and ember.json to add it to the list of packages, but that doesn't seem like best practice. Is there some convention I'm missing?

On the subject of building ember.js: on Ubuntu, I needed to `sudo aptitude install ruby-1.9.1-full libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev nodejs`, then `sudo gem install {rake,github-upload,bundler}`, then `bundle install`, then `bundle exec rake`. This is probably old hat to a Ruby hacker, but *phew*.

Comment: Surprised that no one has answered this, I would also like to know about this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the "official" add-ons have a Rakefile of their own to build the add-on in much the same way that Ember itself is built. As you've correctly observed, you'll need certain dependencies installed before you can use the Rakefile. I think Ruby, RubyGems, Rake and Node.js should be all you need to install (possibly libxml2-dev and libxslt1-dev), then a "bundle install" should take care of anything else the Rakefile needs.

In the case of sproutcore-routing there is no Rakefile because the entire add-on is in lib/core.js so all you have to do is copy that file to sproutcore-routing.js and you're good to go.